# FSR presses to increase variable on a display

Tags: arduino, led

Update: So I'm getting the error: "expected initializer before 'fsrAnalogPin'" with this code. Can someone help me sort this out?

```
// testshapes demo for Adafruit RGBmatrixPanel library.
// Demonstrates the drawing abilities of the RGBmatrixPanel library.
// For 32x32 RGB LED matrix:
// http://www.adafruit.com/products/607

// Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada & Phil Burgess/PaintYourDragon
// for Adafruit Industries.
// BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution.

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>   // Core graphics library
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h> // Hardware-specific library



// If your 32x32 matrix has the SINGLE HEADER input,
// use this pinout:
#define CLK 8  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
#define OE  9
#define LAT 10
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2
#define D   A3
#define PULLUP true              //use the AVR's internal pullup resistor
#define INVERT true              //low level means fsr pressed
#define DEBOUNCE_TIME 50         //milliseconds
// If your matrix has the DOUBLE HEADER input, use:
//#define CLK 8  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
//#define LAT 9
//#define OE  10
//#define A   A3
//#define B   A2
//#define C   A1
//#define D   A0
RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, D, CLK, LAT, OE, false);

void loop(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  matrix.begin();

  // draw a pixel in solid white
  matrix.drawPixel(0, 0, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 7)); 
  delay(500);

  // fix the screen with green
  matrix.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32, matrix.Color333(0, 7, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw a box in yellow
  matrix.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw an 'X' in red
  matrix.drawLine(0, 0, 31, 31, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  matrix.drawLine(31, 0, 0, 31, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw a blue circle
  matrix.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, matrix.Color333(0, 0, 7));
  delay(500);

  // fill a violet circle
  matrix.fillCircle(21, 21, 10, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 7));
  delay(500);

  // fill the screen with 'black'
  matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(0, 0, 0));

  // draw some text!
  matrix.setCursor(1, 0);    // start at top left, with one pixel of spacing
  matrix.setTextSize(1);     // size 1 == 8 pixels high
  matrix.setTextWrap(false); // Don't wrap at end of line - will do ourselves

  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,7));
  matrix.println("FIST");
  matrix.println(" BUMP");

  // print each letter with a rainbow color
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,0,0));
  matrix.print('C');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,4,0)); 
  matrix.print('O');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,0));
  matrix.print('U');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(4,7,0)); 
  matrix.print('N');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,7,0));  
  matrix.println('T');

{
const int fsr_pin = A4;             //connect fsr from this pin to ground
int read fsrAnalogPin = 4;
    fsr_pin.read(); 
    if( fsr_pin.wasPressed() ){
        counter = counter + 1
        matrix.setTextColor( matrix.Color333(0,7,7) );
        matrix.print( counter )
    }
}

  // whew!
}

void loop() {
  // do nothing
}
```

if someone can help me with my code I would be very grateful. What I'm trying to do is: Using a force-sensitive resistor, I want to count a given amount of pressure on the FSR with an arduino, that then displays each tap on an LED matrix. In other words, I have a glove with an FSR on it, and I want to count "fist bumps" that then display on an 32x32 Adafruit LED matrix.

Here's an example of what I want it to look like: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kq-ADrtz4mSzNWUTJoNGlBSU0/view?usp=sharing

That is just a static number on the bottom though. I need help making the code to connect a counting variable to the FSR "bumps." It's probably pretty simple but I'm entirely new to this so it's a lot to learn. So any help is appreciated

Here is what I have for code:

```css
// testshapes demo for Adafruit RGBmatrixPanel library.
// Demonstrates the drawing abilities of the RGBmatrixPanel library.
// For 32x32 RGB LED matrix:
// http://www.adafruit.com/products/607

// Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada & Phil Burgess/PaintYourDragon
// for Adafruit Industries.
// BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution.

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>   // Core graphics library
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h> // Hardware-specific library



// If your 32x32 matrix has the SINGLE HEADER input,
// use this pinout:
#define CLK 8  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
#define OE  9
#define LAT 10
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2
#define D   A3
#define FSR_PIN A4               //connect fsr from this pin to ground
#define PULLUP true              //use the AVR's internal pullup resistor
#define INVERT true              //low level means fsr pressed
#define DEBOUNCE_TIME 50         //milliseconds
// If your matrix has the DOUBLE HEADER input, use:
//#define CLK 8  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
//#define LAT 9
//#define OE  10
//#define A   A3
//#define B   A2
//#define C   A1
//#define D   A0
RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, D, CLK, LAT, OE, false);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  matrix.begin();
  
  // draw a pixel in solid white
  matrix.drawPixel(0, 0, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 7)); 
  delay(500);

  // fix the screen with green
  matrix.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32, matrix.Color333(0, 7, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw a box in yellow
  matrix.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 0));
  delay(500);
  
  // draw an 'X' in red
  matrix.drawLine(0, 0, 31, 31, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  matrix.drawLine(31, 0, 0, 31, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  delay(500);
  
  // draw a blue circle
  matrix.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, matrix.Color333(0, 0, 7));
  delay(500);
  
  // fill a violet circle
  matrix.fillCircle(21, 21, 10, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 7));
  delay(500);
  
  // fill the screen with 'black'
  matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(0, 0, 0));
  
  // draw some text!
  matrix.setCursor(1, 0);    // start at top left, with one pixel of spacing
  matrix.setTextSize(1);     // size 1 == 8 pixels high
  matrix.setTextWrap(false); // Don't wrap at end of line - will do ourselves

  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,7));
  matrix.println("FIST");
  matrix.println(" BUMP");
  
  // print each letter with a rainbow color
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,0,0));
  matrix.print('C');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,4,0)); 
  matrix.print('O');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,0));
  matrix.print('U');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(4,7,0)); 
  matrix.print('N');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,7,0));  
  matrix.println('T');

  void loop(void)
{
   fsr.read();
   if (fsr.wasPressed()) {
       Serial.print(++counter, DEC);
       Serial.println(" steps");
   }

  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,7,7)); 
  matrix.print("29291");


  // whew!
}

void loop() {
  // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to remove the `loop()` method from `setup()`.

In the `void loop()` method, making following changes should get things working.

```
void loop(){
    fsr.read(); 
    if( fsr.wasPressed() ){
        counter = counter + 1
        matrix.setTextColor( matrix.Color333(0,7,7) );
        matrix.print( counter )
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

```
// testshapes demo for Adafruit RGBmatrixPanel library.
// Demonstrates the drawing abilities of the RGBmatrixPanel library.
// For 32x32 RGB LED matrix:
// http://www.adafruit.com/products/607

// Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada & Phil Burgess/PaintYourDragon
// for Adafruit Industries.
// BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution.

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>   // Core graphics library
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h> // Hardware-specific library



// If your 32x32 matrix has the SINGLE HEADER input,
// use this pinout:
#define CLK 8  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
#define OE  9
#define LAT 10
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2
#define D   A3
#define PULLUP true              //use the AVR's internal pullup resistor
#define INVERT true              //low level means fsr pressed
#define DEBOUNCE_TIME 50         //milliseconds
// If your matrix has the DOUBLE HEADER input, use:
//#define CLK 8  // MUST be on PORTB! (Use pin 11 on Mega)
//#define LAT 9
//#define OE  10
//#define A   A3
//#define B   A2
//#define C   A1
//#define D   A0
RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, D, CLK, LAT, OE, false);

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  matrix.begin();

  // draw a pixel in solid white
  matrix.drawPixel(0, 0, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 7)); 
  delay(500);

  // fix the screen with green
  matrix.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32, matrix.Color333(0, 7, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw a box in yellow
  matrix.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw an 'X' in red
  matrix.drawLine(0, 0, 31, 31, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  matrix.drawLine(31, 0, 0, 31, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  delay(500);

  // draw a blue circle
  matrix.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, matrix.Color333(0, 0, 7));
  delay(500);

  // fill a violet circle
  matrix.fillCircle(21, 21, 10, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 7));
  delay(500);

  // fill the screen with 'black'
  matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(0, 0, 0));

  // draw some text!
  matrix.setCursor(1, 0);    // start at top left, with one pixel of spacing
  matrix.setTextSize(1);     // size 1 == 8 pixels high
  matrix.setTextWrap(false); // Don't wrap at end of line - will do ourselves

  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,7));
  matrix.println("FIST");
  matrix.println(" BUMP");

  // print each letter with a rainbow color
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,0,0));
  matrix.print('C');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,4,0)); 
  matrix.print('O');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,0));
  matrix.print('U');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(4,7,0)); 
  matrix.print('N');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,7,0));  
  matrix.println('T');
}

void loop(){
    const int fsr_pin = A4;             //connect fsr from this pin to ground
    int read fsrAnalogPin = 4;
    fsr_pin.read(); 
    if( fsr_pin.wasPressed() ){
        counter = counter + 1
        matrix.setTextColor( matrix.Color333(0,7,7) );
        matrix.print( counter )
    }
}
```

I will also suggest following proper indentation. That will make your code readable. It would be also great if you revise your Arduino prog. concepts.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. It's giving me this error now: exit status 1
'fsr' was not declared in this scope. Could you maybe clarify how can I define 'fsr' in the code? And are you saying I change 'setup' to 'loop' at the top of the code, otherwise it gives me "cannot have function before {" when I add it to the middle. Thanks for whatever help you can provide.